# Illegal string offset 'id' laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending these objects to server to fetch the record and update it. But it is giving me the below given error.

[image: error]

Wnen I add `dd`, I see this message.

[image: dd]

**FilterController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request, Filter $filter)
{
    $filters = collect($request->filters);
    dd($filters);
    $filters->each(function ($item) use ($request, $filter) {
        if (isset($item['name']) && isset($item['latin'])) {
            $data = [
                'category_id' => $request->category_id,
                'name' => $item['name'],
                'latin' => $item['latin'],
                'field' => $item['field'],
            ];
            $filter_item = Filter::query()->firstOrCreate(['id' => $item['id'] ?? null]);
            $filter_item->fill($data)->save();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        if (isset($item['value'])) {
            foreach($item['value'] as $value) {
                $filter_item->values()->updateOrCreate(
                    ['id' => $value['id']],
                    ['value' => $value['value']]
                );
            }
        }
    });
    return redirect()->route('filters.index');
}
```

Comment: Your $value variable contains the value of blue. As you are iterating through the array and taking it's value to iterate through. So it's not an array. It's a string right now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your screen short you don't have `$value['id']`

it will be like

```php
if (isset($item['value'])) {
            foreach($item['value'] as $key => $value) {
                $filter_item->values()->updateOrCreate(
                    ['id' => $key],
                    ['value' => $value]
                );
            }
        }
```

as `$item['value']` is normal array with only index

Comment: I get this error again now . https://i.stack.imgur.com/h31hK.png

Comment: yeah it is correct you should remove `id` from update

Comment: If I remove `id` from update . It did not update.

Comment: yeah becouse `one` value is already exist

Comment: I have a form like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Uwk.png . This may be each group has several have a subgroup.

Comment: then you need to match with `filter_id` and based on update `value`

Comment: How? https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7yM0.png like this?

Comment: $key is not flter_id you need to get from somewhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239800/discussion-between-mahmoud-khosravi-and-kamlesh-paul).